# Is there a way to conditionally cascade delete in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to find a clean way to conditionally delete foreign key references in my database when deleting an object. Cascade delete seems like it's almost exactly what I'm looking for, but there are some things that I don't want to delete, such as history models.

Currently I'm taking this approach, but it's very messy.

```
Foo foo = _Context.Foo.Where(item => item.Name = something.name).FirstOrDefault();

if(foo != null)
{
    // We can assume that foo has a history model element that we want to preserve
    // Therefore cascade delete is not an option
    Bar bar = _Context.Bar.Where(item => item.Name = foo.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if(bar != null)
    {
        Foobar foobar = _Context.Foobar.Where(item => item.Name = bar.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        _Context.Remove(foobar);
    }

    _Context.Remove(bar);
}

_Context.Remove(foo);
_Context.SaveChanges();
```

This approach is not very scalable because I have many different models with other model types nested within them. This example is only 3 layers deep, but depending on the operation I'm performing the models all change and the depth could be even greater.

I've read about a blog/post cascade delete example, and I understand that `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` applies to the blog, not the post. Is there a way to replicate this behavior at the post level?

Comment: I don' understand your question. Cascaded delete is defined per FK, not on an entity as a whole, if that helps you.